# Template member function syntax

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I'm currently implementing containers in C++ and I have a question about the syntax used to declare member functions.

I have a *Vector_declaration.hpp* file where I declare the vector class and all its components for instance: `reference operator[](size_type n);`
Where `reference` is defined by `typedef typename Allocator::reference reference;`

In another file called *vector.hpp* I want to implement the elements defined in *Vector_declaration.hpp* and I found that the only way to do that was with the following syntax:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
typename vector<T, Allocator>::reference
vector<T, Allocator>::operator[](size_type n)
```

I don't understand what role `typename vector<T, Allocator>::reference` plays here, why do I have to rewrite the `typename` each time I use it in a function, shouldn't I be able to just use the word `reference` instead?
Is there anyway to do so, so the code would be cleaner?

Comment: Just an opinion on the filenames: Instead of `Vector_declaration.hpp` and `Vector.hpp` for the implementation I suggest `Vector.hpp` for the declaration and `Vector_impl.hpp` for the implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator> 
typename vector<T, Allocator>::reference 
vector<T, Allocator>::operator[](size_type n);
```

The `typename vector<T, Allocator>::reference` is the return type of the method. Consider how it would look without templates:

```
struct foo {
   using reference = int&;
   reference bar();
};

foo::reference foo::bar() { /*...*/ }
```

`reference` is declared in the scope of `foo`. If you want to refer to it outside of the scope of `foo` you need to qualify the name `foo::reference`. Because this:

```
reference foo::bar() { /*...*/ }
```

would result in an error: "reference is not declared".

Moreover, `typename` is needed because `vector<T, Allocator>::reference` is a dependent name (ie you need to tell the compiler that it is a type, in a specialization it might be the name of a member or not exist at all).

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer ! I find the syntax a bit heavy but I guess I don't have a choice right now :D

Comment: @Ajvar I read the question as "What does this code mean?" for a "How to write it differently?" interpretation see the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

With trailing return type (C++11), you might do:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
auto vector<T, Allocator>::operator[](size_type n)
-> reference
{
// ...
}
```

Before `vector<T, Allocator>::`, you are not yet in scope class, so writing just `reference` would refer to the one in global scope (`::reference`).

So you can use types/using from the class in parameters and trailing return type (and in scope of the function).

Comment: It looks nicer thanks, for now I only can use C++98 tho, but I'll use this syntax later (: